# Django ModelChoiceField not adding attrs to html in admin

Tags: django-admin, django-forms

I am trying to write a Django app and having some difficulty customizing the admin for one of my models.

Here is a simplified version of the model I am working with:

```
class Server(django.db.models.Model):
    name = django.db.models.CharField(max_length=40)
    is_virtual = django.db.models.BooleanField()
    host = django.db.models.ForeignKey(u'self', blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is the form I am trying to tie in to the admin:

```
class ServerAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Server

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ServerAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.instance.is_virtual:
            # I don't know why these are not working
            self.fields['host'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
            self.fields['host'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

And here is the admin code (In reality there are more fields and other fieldsets):

```
class ServerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('name', 'is_virtual', 'host')
        }),
    )
    form = admin_forms.ServerAdminForm
    save_as = True
```

My goal is to have the admin show the host field only when is_virtual is True. I tried deleting host from fields and setting it to none in the form **init** above, but both of those crashed the page because I have it listed in fieldsets.

So my first question would be: Is there a clean way to dynamically modify fieldsets based on the instance? I tried that approach for a few hours, but got nowhere on google and the django docs.

After failing with the above approach, I decided to try to disable the ModelChoiceField when is_virtual is False. That is the form code I have above. When I step through the code everything seems to get set correctly, but when I look at the html source I see no disabled or readonly attribute. I tried switching host to a CharField to see if that changed anything and when I looked at the html, the attributes were set.

I am not sure if I am missing something in the documentation saying that you cannot disable ModelChoiceFields, or if I am just doing something wrong, but I would appreciate any advice on how to disable the ModelChoiceField.

So I am looking for either a way to dynamically modify the fieldsets based on the instance or a way to disable the ModelChoiceField. I am also open to other approaches to solving this problem if you think there is a better way to do it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update**

I was able to get the desired results using the javascript approach from the selected answer.

I am however still curious why the approach I was taking, using self.fields['host'].widget.attrs, did not work for the ModelChoiceField.

Comment: Hi JSchrantz, were you able to figure out why setting widget attributes did not work for ModelChoiceField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to toggle the field display on click, you should use javascript.  See: [How To Collapse Just One Field in Django Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420516/how-to-collapse-just-one-field-in-django-admin/2530217#2530217)

If not, you can create or modify your form dynamically using base_fields in `__init__`:

```
    if not self.instance.is_virtual:
        ServerAdminForm.host = django.db.models.ForeignKey(u'self', blank=True, null=True)
        ServerAdminForm.base_fields['host'] = ServerAdminForm.host
```

See: [Monkey patching a Django form class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930512/monkey-patching-a-django-form-class/3930819#3930819)

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that tomorrow when I get to work. Any ideas on why the html of the field does not have the attributes disabled or readonly?

Comment: The javascript method worked great, Thanks. I am still curious why my above approach was failing though.