# How to activate a charfield using a checkbox in django?

Tags: django, django-models

How can I create a checkbox in django and when that box is ticked, then a charfield below it is activated.  (When the box is not checked the charfield below it should not be active) .

Here's my `models.py`:

```
    ...
    frequent_flyer_number = models.CharField('Freq Flyer No',max_length=30,unique=True)
    frequent_flyer_number2 = models.CharField('Freq Flyer No2',max_length=30,unique=True, blank=True)
    frequent_flyer_number3 = models.CharField('Freq Flyer No3',max_length=30,unique=True, blank=True)
    frequent_flyer_number4 = models.CharField('Freq Flyer No4',max_length=30,unique=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

I want frequent_flyer_number2,3,4 to be activated only when the checkbox is ticked.

Answer (score 1):

You should add some javascript to your template to toggle your field visibility (or the [`disabled`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) attribute).  See: [How To Collapse Just One Field in Django Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420516/how-to-collapse-just-one-field-in-django-admin/2530217#2530217)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function show_hide() {
        var is_checked = $('#id_first_field').attr('checked');
        $('.second_field,.third_field,.fourth_field')[is_checked ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    }
    show_hide();
    $('#id_first_field').change(show_hide);
});
```

(If it is not for your admin, make sure you use [jQuery](http://scriptsrc.net/) as well)

Comment: so in other words this is what i would implement in my base.html template?

Comment: I believe a better fit will be in the bottom of a specific template (i.e. `myform.html`).